# ¿Como encriptar passwor con `cript()` de php para sistema de login?

Tags: php

Tengo una encriptación con cript de la siguiente forma.

```
         $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pwd');
         function saltAleatoria() {
             $caracteres = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz0123456789";
             $salt = "";
             for ($i = 5; $i < 35; $i++) { 
                  $salt .= $caracteres[rand(5,35)]; 
             };
             return $salt;
         }

         $num = "14";
         $salt = '$2y$'.$num.'$'.saltAleatoria().'$';
         $passwordConSalt = crypt($password, $salt);
```

Pretendo guardar `$passwordConSalt`en la base de datos pero me surge una duda, al momento de que un usuario haga un login, ¿como puedo comparar su contraseña que ingresa con la que está guardado en mi base de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te agrego un ejemplo de como seria, espero te ayude:

Codigo para encriptación.

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

// Generamos un salt aleatoreo, de 22 caracteres para Bcrypt
$salt = substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes('30')), 0, 22);

// A Crypt no le gustan los '+' así que los vamos a reemplazar por puntos.
$salt = strtr($salt, array('+' => '.')); 

// Generamos el hash
$hash = crypt($password, '$2y$10$' . $salt);

// Guardamos los datos en la base de datos
$db = new PDO(.....);
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, pass) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($nombre, $hash)); 
?>
```

Y para validar la contraseña que esta almacenada en la base de datos contra un valor proporcionado por el usuario sería algo así:

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

// Validamos $nombre...

// Extraemos el hash de la base de datos
$db = new PDO(......);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT pass
                      FROM usuarios
                      WHERE nombre = ?');

$stmt->execute(array($nombre));
$dbHash = $stmt->fetchcolumn();

// Recalculamos a ver si el hash coincide.
if (crypt($password, $dbHash) == $dbHash)
    echo 'El usuario ha sido autenticado correctamente';
else
    die('Mal Password');
?>
```

Creamos una función que haga el trabajo Para que nuestra contraseña sea más segura, vamos a crear una función que realice un salt aleatorio. El valor que se generará aleatoriamente para cada hash serán los últimos 22 caracteres.

```
<?php
    function crypt_blowfish($password, $digito = 7) {
    $set_salt = './1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $digito);
for($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++)
{
    $salt .= $set_salt[mt_rand(0, 22)];
}
    return crypt($password, $salt);
}
?>
```

Para crear el hash con la función que recién creamos solamente tenemos que escribirlo de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
$password = crypt_blowfish('stringdondeestaralacontraseña');
?>
```

Ahora para validar la contraseña que recién se ha creado y suponiendo que se guardo en la base de datos, vamos a recuperar ese valor en la variable $passwordenBD lo que se obtiene es:

```
<?php
$passwordenBD = '$2a$07$yMoJrJpwEPrmVnZx4KIyNuOAiOMQksjkV1EW0YRgVe33eYe/yT60y';

//Micontraseña representa el valor capturado desde el usuario

if( crypt('micontraseña', $passwordenBD) == $passwordenBD) {
 echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: entiendo que `$passwordenBD` es el password que sacas de la base de datos después de hacer un select, pero en el if encriptas la contraseña que ingresa el usuario usando como salt lo obtenido de la BD, esto no genera otro hash? (no entiendo como funciona eso).

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es comparar el valor ingresado, junto al valor de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Igualmente deberias de guardar en algun lado `$salt` para que al momento de que el usuario se logue con su contraseña puedas desencriptar con su llave que se genero al momento de registrarse.